# Open and edit .js file with php

Tags: php, javascript, json

Is it possible to edit a js file with php? I have a javascript function with some parameters and i would like to know if  i can edit (later) this function to add some other parameters with php.

My function looks like this right now.

```
function test_10020(){ 
    {
        "PubId":"1256",
        "cID":"554",
        "helper":"custom",
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Yes you can. .js files are just text files. The *real* question is: will you be able to parse the file to know where to make the changes, or can you just overwrite the entire file?

Comment: It's probably possible, but I would use something like an ini / preferences file (or database) and have php encode that to a json string to make it available in js.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes i will be able to parse the file because i only going to add some lines to files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use header() in PHP to manipulate a PHP file to be a javascript file

start your PHP file with this line:

```
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

And just point your javascript tag to the PHP file.

Then you can make all your parameters dynamically in the "javascript" file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to edit any write-allowed file via php, but not recommended to.

If you need to pass parameters from a php script, I'd recommend printing them into the page as standalone globals.

F.ex:

```
<html>
    </blah>
    <script>
        var param = <?=$param;?>;
    </script>
    </blah>    
</html>
```

Then they can be directly accessed by any js that runs after they are printed.

Comment: Adding parameters like this is usually the better solution, although it might be more efficient to include it in the .js file itself if it is something that you change manually and infrequently.

Comment: @GolezTrol, Not infrequently, you need to use dynamicaly generated values from your php script, but the scale does not justify using ajax. This is where this solution shines. Constants do not justify injecting data from php at all.

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<html>
<script src='js_code_gen_by_php.php'></script>
<script> my_powerful_func(); </script>
</html>
```

file: js_code_gen_by_php.php

```
<?php
$my_private_value = 'super_private key';
echo 'function my_powerful_func(){';
echo 'alert("' . $my_private_value . '");'
echo '}';
?>
```