# How to get PHP to change a JavaScript file to communicate with bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to get PHP to change a JavaScript file. I want to have a form with a simple toggle switch and password like this:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<form action = "something.php">
<input type = "password" placeholder = "Password..." name = "PASSWORD" id = "password"><br><br>
<label class="switch">
  <input type = "checkbox" name = "TOGGLE" id = "toggleSwitch">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The form has a password and toggle switch. The PHP should validate the password, and if it is "1234", then if the toggle switch is checked, it will change the JavaScript file to "alert('ON');", if it is off, it will change to "alert('OFF');". There is a bookmarklet that will change functionality for what the form is at. The code is this

```js
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://shimmering-raspy-roarer.glitch.me/script.js';})();
```

I'm not sure how to write this PHP. I am using [glitch.com](https://glitch.com) to make this website.

Comment: don't do that, it's not a good idea, php should not modify js code. And you don't need to, use a if else to do what you want depending on the state of the switch

Comment: I want to use an html form to communicate with a bookmarklet. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Duplicate Question -->
[Open and edit .js file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554268/open-and-edit-js-file-with-php)

Comment: **change** the JavaScript file to "alert('ON');" , do you mean **trigger** a javascript statement to show an alert box with the word 'ON' ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to change the Javascript file. only thing you need is write a condition whenever it was true, then show the alert.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <input type = "password" placeholder = "Password..." name = "PASSWORD" id = "password"><br><br>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "TOGGLE" id = "toggleSwitch">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    
    <script>
        <!-- The alert code here -->
        <?php
        if ($_GET['PASSWORD'] == 1234) {
            $message = $_GET['TOGGLE'] ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
            
            echo "alert('$message');";
        }
        ?>
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the alert code here"?

Comment: Javascript has some functions to show alert to users. I mean `alert('OFF')`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I knew that. Thanks!